# erlang JSON data - how to select only one value

Tags: arrays, json, nested, erlang

in erlang language I receive this kids of JSON data:

```
{"Time":"2020-08-16T15:28:55","BME680":{"Temperature":29.8,"Humidity":55.5,"Pressure":1003.5,"Gas":422.24},"PressureUnit":"hPa","TempUnit":"C"}
```

or

```
{"Time":"2020-08-16T11:39:49","SI7021":{"Temperature":32.4,"Humidity":99.9},"TempUnit":"C"}
```

I need to select only one value per each JSON data for example:
based on "BME680" value

```
{"Temperature":29.8,"Humidity":54.8,"Pressure":1005.0,"Gas":1513.60}
```

or
based on "SI7021" value

```
{"Temperature":32.4,"Humidity":99.9}
```

How can acive this task in erlang language ?
If it cold be simpler I need to extract the second value of each JSON data.

Comment: The example what you provided is not correct. In your example you provide JSON format, not a tuple. JSON - `{"Temperature":32.4,"Humidity":99.9}`. Tuple - `{"Temperature",32.4, "Humidity",99.9}`. Proplist - `[{"Temperature",32.4},{"Humidity",99.9}]`. Please, update your question with correct example of tuple which you are trying to work with. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For decode JSON format into Erlang format data like [proplists](https://erlang.org/doc/man/proplists.html) or into the [maps](https://erlang.org/doc/man/maps.html), you can try to use 3rd party library [jiffy](https://github.com/davisp/jiffy), then you can use simple pattern matching, eg:

Maps:

```erlang
1> JSON = "{\"Time\":\"2020-08-17T05:32:09\",\"BME680\":{\"Temperature\":29.6,\"Humidity\":54.6,\"Pressure\":1003.9,\"Gas\":1517.91},\"PressureUnit\":\"hPa\",\"TempUnit\":\"C\"}".
2> Map = jiffy:decode(JSON,[return_maps]).
3> #{<<"BME680">> := BME680} = Map.
4> BME680.
#{<<"Gas">> => 1517.91,<<"Humidity">> => 54.6, <<"Pressure">> => 1003.9,<<"Temperature">> => 29.6}
```

Proplists:

```erlang
1> JSON = "{\"Time\":\"2020-08-17T05:32:09\",\"BME680\":{\"Temperature\":29.6,\"Humidity\":54.6,\"Pressure\":1003.9,\"Gas\":1517.91},\"PressureUnit\":\"hPa\",\"TempUnit\":\"C\"}".
2> {Proplists} = jiffy:decode(JSON).
3> [BME680] = [V || {K, V} <- Proplists, K == <<"BME680">>].
4> BME680.
{[{<<"Temperature">>,29.6},{<<"Humidity">>,54.6},{<<"Pressure">>,1003.9},{<<"Gas">>,1517.91}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use 2 modules from mochiweb project:

1. https://github.com/mochi/mochiweb/blob/master/src/mochijson2.erl
2. https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mochi/mochiweb/master/src/mochinum.erl

Put them in some folder (f.e. test) and run erl shell and compile this files:

```erlang
alexei@MacBook-Pro test % erl
Erlang/OTP 23 [erts-11.0] [source] [64-bit] [smp:8:8] [ds:8:8:10] [async-threads:1] [hipe] [dtrace]

Eshell V11.0  (abort with ^G)
1> c("mochijson2.erl").
{ok,mochijson2}

2> c("mochinum.erl").
{ok,mochinum}
```

Decode json-as-text to json-as-erlang-term:

```
3> Body = "{\"Time\":\"2020-08-16T15:28:55\",\"BME680\":{\"Temperature\":29.8,\"Humidity\":55.5,\"Pressure\":1003.5,\"Gas\":422.24},\"PressureUnit\":\"hPa\",\"TempUnit\":\"C\"}".
"{\"Time\":\"2020-08-16T15:28:55\",\"BME680\":{\"Temperature\":29.8,\"Humidity\":55.5,\"Pressure\":1003.5,\"Gas\":422.24},\"PressureUnit\":\"hPa\",\"TempUnit\":\"C\"}"

4> {struct, Map} = mochijson2:decode(Body).
{struct,[{<<"Time">>,<<"2020-08-16T15:28:55">>},
         {<<"BME680">>,
          {struct,[{<<"Temperature">>,29.8},
                   {<<"Humidity">>,55.5},
                   {<<"Pressure">>,1003.5},
                   {<<"Gas">>,422.24}]}},
         {<<"PressureUnit">>,<<"hPa">>},
         {<<"TempUnit">>,<<"C">>}]}
```

Retrive the items you need:

```
5> {struct, Obj1} = proplists:get_value(<<"BME680">>, Map).
{struct,[{<<"Temperature">>,29.8},
         {<<"Humidity">>,55.5},
         {<<"Pressure">>,1003.5},
         {<<"Gas">>,422.24}]}

6> Item1 = proplists:lookup(<<"Temperature">>, Obj1).  
{<<"Temperature">>,29.8}

7> Item2 = proplists:lookup(<<"Humidity">>, Obj1).   
{<<"Humidity">>,55.5}
```

And encode erlang term to text:

```
8> List = [Item1, Item2].
[{<<"Temperature">>,29.8},{<<"Humidity">>,55.5}]

9> iolist_to_binary(mochijson2:encode({struct, List})).
<<"{\"Temperature\":29.8,\"Humidity\":55.5}">>
```

There is a very short documentation for mochijson2, but it is easy to learn just practice in shell.

Answer (score -1):

You need to familiarize yourself with [rebar3](https://www.rebar3.org), which is erlang's package manager.  Then, you can use a package like [jsx](https://hex.pm/packages/jsx), which will allow you to convert between binary types and maps.  First, you will need to convert whatever it is that you call "JSON" to a binary type, perhaps using `tuple_to_list()` then `list_to_binary()`, then you can use the jsx package to convert the binary to a map, which will enable you to extract the target value from the map.

Here's an example:

my.erl:

```
json_to_map(Bin) ->
    jsx:decode(
      %%<<"{\"data\": [1, 2, 3]}">>,
      Bin,
      [return_maps]
    ).
```

In the shell:

```
~/erlang_programs/myapp$ rebar3 compile
===> Verifying dependencies...
===> Compiling myapp
src/my.erl:2: Warning: export_all flag enabled - all functions will be exported

~/erlang_programs/myapp$ rebar3 shell
===> Verifying dependencies...
===> Compiling myapp
Erlang/OTP 20 [erts-9.3] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [ds:4:4:10] [async-threads:1] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Eshell V9.3  (abort with ^G)

1> Bin1 = <<"{\"A\": 100, \"B\":{\"x\": 4,\"y\": [1,2,3]}}">>.
<<"{\"A\": 100, \"B\":{\"x\": 4,\"y\": [1,2,3]}}">>

2> Bin2 = <<"{\"A\":200, \"C\":{\"a\": 6, \"b\": [3,4,5]}}">>.
<<"{\"A\":200, \"C\":{\"a\": 6, \"b\": [3,4,5]}}">>

3> M1 = my:json_to_map(Bin1).                                 
#{<<"A">> => 100,
  <<"B">> => #{<<"x">> => 4,<<"y">> => [1,2,3]}}

4> M2 = my:json_to_map(Bin2).                                 
#{<<"A">> => 200,
  <<"C">> => #{<<"a">> => 6,<<"b">> => [3,4,5]}}


5> [V1] = maps:values( maps:without([<<"A">>], M1)).
[#{<<"x">> => 4,<<"y">> => [1,2,3]}]

6> V1.
#{<<"x">> => 4,<<"y">> => [1,2,3]}

7> [V2] = maps:values( maps:without([<<"A">>], M2)).
[#{<<"a">> => 6,<<"b">> => [3,4,5]}]

8> V2.
#{<<"a">> => 6,<<"b">> => [3,4,5]}

9>
```

Answer (score -1):

Hi following your advice is it correct my below code if "Body" is equal to:

```
    "{\"Time\":\"2020-08-17T05:32:09\",\"BME680\":{\"Temperature\":29.6,\"Humidity\":54.6,\"Pressure\":1003.9,\"Gas\":1517.91},\"PressureUnit\":\"hPa\",\"TempUnit\":\"C\"}"
```

my code

```
     ....
     eBody = jiffy:decode(<<Body>>),
     Map = #eBody,
     #{"BME680" := BME680} = Map,
     newbody = jiffy:encode(BME680),
     HTTPOptions = [],
     Options = [],
     R = httpc:request(Method, {URL, Header, Type, newbody},HTTPOptions, Options),
     ....
```

I'm newbie in erlang.

Comment: For decode JSON into `maps` you need call `jiffy:decode(JSON, [return_maps])`, and then you can do  `#{<<"BME680">> := BME680} = Map`. P.S. Please accept the one of  answers and move all communications into comments under the chosen correct answer.

Comment: ok @viacheslav when I make `Map = jiffy:decode(JSON,[return_maps]),`  I receive ` #{<<"BME680">> =>
      #{<<"Gas">> => 1517.91,<<"Humidity">> => 54.6,<<"Pressure">> => 1003.9,
        <<"Temperature">> => 29.6},
  <<"PressureUnit">> => <<"hPa">>,<<"TempUnit">> => <<"C">>,
  <<"Time">> => <<"2020-08-17T05:32:09">>}.`  but after extractin the correct data as you told me than I need to remap into JSON format is it ocrrect this code because I receive an error ? `#{"BME680" := BME680} = Map,
newJSON = jiffy:encode(BME680),`

Comment: you get error because after decode the keys type will change, from `"BME680"` to `<<"BME680">>`, so, correct way will be looks like `#{<<"BME680">> := BME680} = Map, NewJSON = jiffy:encode(BME680)`. P.S. the name of variable `newJSON` is wrong, by reason that this is atom, correct variable name is `NewJSON` - Camelcase(variable), Lowercase(atom).

Comment: On this line `#{<<"BME680">> := BME680} = Map,` I receive this error `{{badmatch,<<"{\"Temperature\":29.6,\"Pressure\":1003.9,\"Humidity\":54.6,\"Gas\":1517.91}">>}` Just ot understand BME6080 is a variable ? I'm unable to print its value to see how it is built.

Comment: I use to print to file BME680 values ` file:write_file("/home/luca/bme.log", io_lib:fwrite("~p.\n", [BME680]),[append]),`

Comment: You can get this error by reason that the variable `BME680` is already defined. Please, retest your code more carefully, because all examples what was provided was tested by my end. Thanks. P.S. Current discussion outside the scope of the question asked

Comment: I was update my answer with the example of your JSON and with `jiffy` decoding. I believe that this example will be more better. Sorry if I confused you a little bit.

Comment: thk for your help. Your answer help me to solve the problem. Now I just need to delete <<...>>  from the output (<<"{\"Temperature\":29.6,\"Pressure\":1003.9,\"Humidity\":54.6,\"Gas\":1517.91}">>.) but this is another job.

Comment: You need convert binary to list - `binary_to_list(<<"{\"Temperature\":29.6,\"Pressure\":1003.9,\"Humidity\":54.6,\"Gas\":1517.91}">>).` and as result will be - `"{\"Temperature\":29.6,\"Pressure\":1003.9,\"Humidity\":54.6,\"Gas\":1517.91}"`. Hope this will be helpful.